# reaching aws instance jupyter notebook from my computer

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I have setup an instance with aws ec2.

my inbounds in security group are:

```
SSH 
TCP 
22 
-Home IP- 

HTTPS 
TCP 
443 
-Home Ip-
```

When I changed a public address in jupyter notebook config file and run the notebook, I would think, I could connect to it with my home web browser.

It says:

```
Jupyter Notebook is running at:
http://ec2-IP-.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8890/
```

But I just get A connection attempt failed

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: You followed the instructions here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/setup-jupyter-configure-server.html

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to add port 8890 to the security group incoming.